# How can i replace '?' with '&' if '?' is already there in the URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, affiliate

For an affiliate with affiliate ID ‘xxxx’, the tracking parameters are:

> ?utm_source=aff_prog&utm_campaign=afts&offer_id=17&aff_id=xxxx

If the URL already contains a ‘?’ (Example: www[dot]companyname[dot]com/products/mobiles-mobile-phones?sort=date), the tracking parameter to be appended should be:

> &utm_source=aff_prog&utm_campaign=afts&offer_id=17&aff_id=xxxx

what I am using is this script to append my affiliate tag to the URL

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');


for (var i = 0, max = links.length; i < max; i++) {
    var _href = links[i].href;

    if (_href.indexOf('amazon.in') !== -1) {
    links[i].href = _href + '?&tag=geek-21';  
    }
    else if (_href.indexOf('snapdeal.com') !== -1) {
    links[i].href = _href + '?utm_source=aff_prog&utm_campaign=afts&offer_id=17&aff_id=10001';  
    }
}
```

if the URL already contains '?' how can I use my above script to tag the '&' as a starting of affiliate tag? like this

> &utm_source=aff_prog&utm_campaign=afts&offer_id=17&aff_id=10001

[see this image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pBpw.png)

Comment: `?&tag=geek-21` does this make sense in the first place?

Comment: why the tag [tag:jquery] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just like you said. Check if the href contains `?` and set the appropriate charcter in front of you parameter list:

```
for (var i = 0, max = links.length; i < max; i++) {
    var _href = links[i].href;

    // this is how to check and set for the appropriate starting character of your parameter list
    var startChar = _href.indexOf("?") === -1 ? "?" : "&";        

    if (_href.indexOf('amazon.in') !== -1) {
        links[i].href = _href + startChar +'tag=geek-21';  
    }
    else if (_href.indexOf('snapdeal.com') !== -1) {
        links[i].href = _href + startChar + 'utm_source=aff_prog&utm_campaign=afts&offer_id=17&aff_id=10001';  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the life saver help :D, that's exactly what I need. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

To replace `?` with `&` for urls with affiliate tag (as a preceding character for `utm_source` parameter) if a question mark `?` already occurs within a url - use the following approach with `String.prototype.replace()` function and specific regex pattern:

```js
var _href = 'www[dot]companyname[dot]com/products/mobiles-mobile-phones?sort=date?utm_source=aff_prog&utm_campaign=afts&offer_id=17&aff_id=xxxx',
    _href = _href.replace(/(?=.*?\?.*?)\?(utm_source=)/, '&$1');

console.log(_href);
```